# How to disable specific index/es or item/s in combobox?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I have a combobox and I need to disable some items/indexes. Here is my code.

```
months = ['january','feruary'.....'december']

cbMonth=ttk.Combobox(frame,values=months)
cbMonth.set(0)
cbMonth.place(relx=xDistance,rely=yDistance,relwidth=xWidth,relheight=yHeight)
cbMonth.update()
```

Let's say I want to disable or grayed out months of january,march and december or index 5,9,12. How to do it in Python. Something like;

```
cbMonth.Index[1].Enabled=false or
cbMonth.cget('january').Disable
```

Comment: The combobox doesn't support the ability to individually configure items in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to disable items in Combobox. But, if you still want to do so you will have to create a custom Combobox.

Here is a demo on how to create a custom Combobox. (you may add custom functionality if you want to).

```py
import tkinter as tk 

class CustomComboBox(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, values=[], validate='none', validatecommand='none',*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.disabled = []
        
        self.values = values
        self.listbox = None
        self.scrollbar = None

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, borderwidth=0, background="white",relief="groove")
        self.entry.configure(validate=validate, validatecommand=validatecommand)
    
        self.entry.pack(expand=True, fill='both', side='left')
        self.entry.bind('<FocusIn>', self._removeListView)
        
        self.arrowButton = tk.Label(self, text='↓', background="white", width=2)
        self.arrowButton.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.arrowButton.bind('<1>', self._listView)

        self.previousIndex = 0

        self.arrowButton.bind('<Enter>', self._changeBackground)
        self.arrowButton.bind('<Leave>', self._changeBackground)

        self.bind('<Configure>', self._updatePos)

    def _changeBackground(self, event):
  
        if str(event.type)=='Enter':
            self.arrowButton.config(bg='#b3d2ff', border=1)
            self.entry.config(border=1)
            

        elif str(event.type) == 'Leave':
            self.arrowButton.config(bg='white', border=0)
            self.entry.config(border=0)
    
    def _listView(self, event=None):
        if self.listbox is None:
            
            self.frame = tk.Frame(background=self['bg'] ,width=self.entry['width']+2)
            self.frame.lift()
            self.frame.place(x=self.winfo_x(), y=self.winfo_y()+self.winfo_height()-2, width=self.winfo_width())
            
            self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self.frame, width=self.entry['width'], border=1, relief="groove", activestyle='none')
            self.listbox.focus()
            self._addValues()
            self.listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self._checkDisabled)
            self.listbox.bind("<Motion>", self._highlight)
            self.listbox.bind("<Leave>", self._removeHighlight)
            
            self.listbox.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')

            self._updateListHeight()
            
        else:
            self._removeListView()

    def _updatePos(self, event):
        if self.listbox:
            self.frame.place_configure(x=self.winfo_x(), y=self.winfo_y()+self.winfo_height()-2, width=self.winfo_width())

    def _updateListHeight(self):

        if self.listbox:
             if self.listbox.size()>5:
                self.listbox.configure(height=5)

                if self.scrollbar is None:
                    self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame, command = self.listbox.yview)
                    self.scrollbar.pack(side='right',  fill="y")
                    self.listbox.config(yscrollcommand = self.scrollbar.set)
           
             else:
                 self.listbox.configure(height=len(self.values))

                 if self.scrollbar:
                    self.scrollbar.destroy()
                    self.scrollbar = None
                

    def _removeListView(self, event=None):
        if self.listbox:
             self.frame.destroy()
             self.listbox = None
             self.scrollbar = None

    def _addValues(self, remove=(False, 0)):

        if self.listbox:

            if remove[0]:
                self.listbox.delete(remove[1])

            else:
                for index, element in enumerate(self.values):
                    self.listbox.insert(index, element)
            
            self._updateDisabled()
            self._updateListHeight()

    def _highlight(self, event):

        self.listbox.itemconfig(self.previousIndex, background='white')
        self.previousIndex = self.listbox.nearest(event.y)

        if self.previousIndex not in self.disabled:
            self.listbox.itemconfig(self.previousIndex, background='#b3d2ff')    

    def _removeHighlight(self, event):
        self.listbox.itemconfig(self.previousIndex, background='white')

    def _checkDisabled(self, event):
        selection = self.listbox.curselection()[0]
        
        if selection in self.disabled:
            self.listbox.selection_clear(selection)
            return 

        else:
            self.entry.delete(0, 'end')
            self.entry.insert(0, self.listbox.get(selection))
            self.entry.focus_set()
            self.event_generate('<<ComboboxSelected>>', when='tail')
      
    
    def _updateDisabled(self, enable=(False, 0)):
        if self.listbox:
            for x in self.disabled:
                self.listbox.itemconfig(x, fg="gray")

            if enable[0]:
                self.listbox.itemconfig(enable[1], fg="black")

    
    def setValues(self, values): # adds values pass a list
        self.values = values
        self._addValues()

    def removeValue(self, index): # removes values pass index

        try:
            self.values.pop(index)
            self._addValues(remove=(True, index))

        except IndexError:
            pass
        
    def disable(self, index:list): # disables the values and given indexes
       
        if index not in self.disabled:
            self.disabled.extend(index)
            self._updateDisabled()
            
        
    def enable(self, index:int): # enables the values at the given index
        try:
            self.disabled.remove(index)
            self._updateDisabled((True, index))

        except ValueError:
            pass

    def getCurrent(self): # returns current text in the entrybox
        return self.entry.get()

    def setDefault(self, index): # sets default value pass index
        
        self.entry.insert(0, self.values[index])
```

(do note that this will not fully function like a Combobox).

Usage:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk
from Combo import CustomComboBox


def truth(event):
    return event.isalpha() or event==""

def fun(event):
    print(monthchoosen.getCurrent())
    monthchoosen.enable(2)

window = tk.Tk() 
window.geometry('350x250') 

ttk.Label(window, text = "Select the Month :",  
        font = ("Times New Roman", 10)).pack()
  

monthchoosen = CustomComboBox(window, validate='key', validatecommand=(window.register(truth), '%P'))

monthchoosen.values = ['January', 'Febuary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July']
monthchoosen.setDefault(1)

monthchoosen.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', fun)

monthchoosen.disable([2, 4, 3])
monthchoosen.pack(expand=True, fill='x')
  
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the values displayed (but not grayed) with postcommand:

```
def f():
    co['values'] = ['c', 'd']

co = ttk.Combobox(values=['a', 'b'], postcommand=f)
```